# Ubuntu Eclipse window disappears

Tags: 14.04, unity, 14.10, eclipse

I am using ubuntu 14.10 with 4 virtual desktops and the newest eclipse ide (4.4.1).
Unfortunately I encounter a very annoying bug with this setup:

- When I try to maximize the eclipse window, it is sometimes maximized to another virtual desktop above or below the current desktop.
- Moreover if I try to minimize the maximize the window it sometimes collapses to a tiny line.

I've made a video where you can see both things. they occur at ~1:10-1.30: http://youtu.be/IeT-qgujf20

I can reproduces this on ubuntu 14.04, 14.10 and the current 15.04 daily and with openjdk-7/8 and oracle jdk. It only occurs in ubuntu and not with kubuntu/ubuntu gnome.

However, I prefer unity :/ Could someone therefore please help to identify, what is causing this bug or how I can create a bug report for it :/

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue. It happens with eclipse and all ecplise based IDEs, e.g. Android Studio, Tizen Wearable IDE,... it is supper annoying. What I so much love about Ubuntu as oppose to my Mac is the ability to arrange windows easily using ctrl+win+arrow key that's super handy especially with smaller laptop screen, but as it is I'd prefer my Mac (it has bigger screen so less need for window arrangement).